# apt-get can't locate any package after fresh install

Tags: release-loki

After finishing a fresh install of elementary OS Loki I tried installing `git` using apt-get but got the following error:

```
E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried installing `apt` but the same error occurs. All of my lists and therefore repositories are in order.

After further instpection I found that `apt-get` cannot find an installation candidate for *any* package.

Answer (score 1):

**For me all that was required was a restart after the first boot.**

The following articles may be helpful if this error persists, though:

- [Unable to install git on Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739959/unable-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-15-10)
- [E: Package 'any package' has no installation candidate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296488/e-package-any-package-has-no-installation-candidate#)